# jQuery .on not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code (reproduced in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGVHs/7/)) that is not working. There are three options in the Type select box. If the first (True/False) is selected I need the first `div` to be shown, and if the second or third options are chosen then the second `div` needs to be shown. What is wrong with this code?

HTML:

```
<form name="editform">
    Selector: <select class="selectors" name="1-type" id="1-type">
        <option value="tf" selected="selected">True/False</option>
        <option value="rd">Radio Button</option>
        <option value="chk">Checkboxes</option>
    </select>

    <div id="seldiv-1">
        Good Value: <select name="1-good_value" id="1-good_value">
                        <option value="true">True</option>
                        <option value="false">False</option>
                    </select>
    </div>

    <div id="textdiv-1" style="display:none;" disabled="disabled">
        Good Value:
        <textarea name="1-good_value" id="1-good_value"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectors').on('change',function (){
        var arr = $(this).name.split("-");
        var id = arr[0];
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val=="tf") {
            $('#textdiv-'+id).hide();
            $('#seldiv'+id).show();
            //Make textarea disabled
            //Make selection enabled
        } else {
            $('#textdiv-'+id).hide();
            $('#seldiv'+id).show();
            //Disable selection
            //Enable textarea
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Run your code with an opened console and you'll see the error message.

Comment: The error wasn't appearing on my site; I didn't even think to try it on jsFiddle. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
var arr = $(this).name.split("-");
```

`on` is working properly but the line above is throwing an exception.

```
var arr = $(this).attr("name").split("-");
```

There are a few ways you could fix this, above is one example.

Answer (score 4):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined.`

Change `$(this).name.split("-");` to `this.name.split("-");`

Answer (score 4):

it is not the `on` but the split function is giving you error, you are trying to get the name  method of jquery object which is not available...either you need to use `attr()` to get the name from jquery object..or use `this` DOM object to get name

try this

```
 var arr = $(this).attr('name').split("-");
```

or

```
 var arr=this.name.split('_');
```

**NOTE  both your codes inside if/else condition is same.. so you won't notice the difference..check it out in your fiddle**

[working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sGVHs/16/)

Comment: This still doesn't work. He uses a variable `tf`, which is not defined. `if(val==tf)`

Answer (score 3):

It 100% does fire, you have an error with `$(this).name` being undefined. I think what you actually wanted to do there was `this.name`

jQuery objects don't act just like DOMElement objects, i.e they don't have the same properties (like `.name`). Next time, open your web console when trying to find out why something doesn't work and you will catch most of your problems there.

Comment: I had the console open but the error didn't appear on my site. I didn't think to try the console in jsFiddle also, but it is appearing there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

your problem is when trying to access `$(this)` which is undefined.

Try just `this` instead

```
this.name.split("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` is not a valid property. Rather use `id` or change the way you access it to `var arr = $(this).attr('name').split("-");`.